# An inequality involving Euler’s $\varphi$-function

Tags: number-theory, inequality, analytic-number-theory

Let $\varphi$ be Euler’s phi-function. I have seen it claimed that $$\varphi(n)/n = O(\log \log n).$$

Could someone either give a proof of this fact or tell me a reference where I can find this proof?

Comment: Since $\varphi(n)<n$, and $\log\log n\to\infty$, $\varphi(n)/n<1<O(\log\log n)$ follows trivially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since trivially $\phi(n)<n$ I suspect that it is about $\frac{n}{\phi(n)}=O(\log(\log(n))$.
In Tenenbaum's Introduction to Analytic and Probabilistic Number Theory, page 84, Theorem 4 the following estimate is proved (in a paper by Rosser and Schönfeld)
$$
\frac{n}{\phi(n)} < e^{\gamma} \log \log n + \frac{5}{2 \log\log n}
$$
for all $n>223092870$.

Comment: a conjecture in Rosser and Schoenfeld was settled later by Nicolas, I put the first page in an answer

Answer (score 2):

this was the first elementary equivalent of the Riemann hypothesis; this is just the first page

[image]